# C array of struct issues

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct individual {
    char name[32];
    int stats[7];
    char role;
};

void create_array(struct individual **array){
    *array = malloc(sizeof(struct individual)); //allocate initial memory space
}

void resize_array(struct individual **array, unsigned char num) {
    printf("%d\n", *array);
    *array = realloc(*array, num * sizeof(struct individual));
    printf("%d\n", *array);
    printf("resize success\n");
}

void problem(struct individual **f_array, unsigned char *f_num) {
  *f_num = 2;

  printf("%d\n", *f_array);
  resize_array(f_array, *f_num);
  printf("%d\n", *f_array);
  strcpy(f_array[*f_num - 1]->name, "test value"); //CRASH LINE
}

int main() {

  unsigned char f_num = 0;
  struct individual *f_array;
  create_array(&f_array);

  problem(&f_array, &f_num);

}
```

This code crashes on the line marked "CRASH LINE". While it is not shown here, doing this same code setting (*f_num = 1) does not result in an error. While passing *f_array as itself (with appropriate alterations to the code in problem) does not result in an error, the values given after problem is exited result in nonsense being given, as the pointer reverts to it's pre-resize state. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Because `strcpy(f_array[*f_num - 1]->name, "test value");` has f_num of zero, giving you a -1 index

Comment: It should be `strcpy((*f_array)[*f_num - 1].name, "test value");`

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, your solution worked first time.

Comment: By the way, `printf("%d\n", *array);` should be `printf("%p\n", (void *)*array);`.

Comment: `*array = realloc(*array, num * sizeof(struct individual));` assigns NULL ptr to array when realloc fails leaving dangling pointer. Use `tmpptr = realloc(...); if (NULL != tmpptr) {*array = tmpptr;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line accessing that value.

The line should read like this:

`strcpy((*f_array)[*f_num - 1].name, "test value"); // doesn't crash any more :)`

To break it down a little bit:

- `f_array` is a pointer to the array  of structs, need to dereference it before indexing
- `[*f_num - 1]` accesses element 1 of the array.